# PHP + MySQL login system

Tags: php, mysql

I have followed one of the many guides online to create a login system using PHP and MySQL. It works fine; you have to log in and then you're redirected to the `/private` directory. Inside it there is a `index.php` file which has to check if you're authenticated, to prevent someone from surfing directly to the `/private` directory. If you aren't you will be redirected back to the login screen. But if you surf to any other file or directory inside /private (e.g. `/private/myprivatefile.html`) you aren't redirected even if you are not logged in. Can you help me please?

Comment: What is your qestion?

Comment: You have to check if the user has logged into the private area in all pages.

Comment: 1. We will need to see code samples to fully assist. 2. Move the check that validates a user to an external file that you can include across all of your private files. Pure html files can't process php so they will need to be changed to PHP files.

Comment: The code that you mentioned that "checks if you're authenticated" on the index page should be used on all other pages in the private directory.

Comment: It's usually a very bad idea to create one of these for anything other than academic purposes. You'll probably make innumerable mistakes while re-inventing the wheel. [Use a PHP guide](http://www.phptherightway.com/) to employ best practices, or use a [PHP framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) that comes standard with this facility.

Comment: You need to use mod_rewrite, assuming you're using Apache.

Comment: you're establishing security via PHP. If PHP isn't involved, then you have no security... HTML files are not parsed through the PHP interpreter, so you've got NO security on those at all.

Comment: @Electrosa is right. You can create a function that checks if the user is logged in (maybe using session data?), and just include whenever you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML files typically don't do any scripting and are considered static pages.  If you want to protect those files then you may need to use the web server to protect the directories.

Another way is to move the static HTML files into a directory that isn't accessible by the web server and use PHP to retrieve the contest of the HTML file.  This way your PHP script will now always run when requesting static content.  For example you would link to the static content like:

```
/private/index.php?file=myprivatefile.html
```

In the PHP file you would pull the file request from the CGI variable file and then pull its contents and return it to the requesting client.  You would do something like this in the PHP file:

```
<?php
   if( CheckAuthentication() )
   {
     $fileName = $_REQUEST['file'];
     $filePath = '{path to protected files}';
     if( is_file( $filePath . $fileName ) )
     {
       readfile( filePath . $fileName );
     }// Endif check if file exists on server
   }// Endif Check user authentication
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use mod_rewrite to redirect all requests to a PHP script, then in that script, handle the request depending on whether the user is authenticated.

Here's a simplified example.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteRule (.*) load.php
```

**load.php**

```
<?php

    // include your auth scripts

    $file = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    // parse $file to extract the requested file

    if ($authenticated && file_exists($file)) {
        readfile($file);
    }
```